# Google charts extra rect tag inside bar

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I use `google-chartAPI` bar style but when I click on a bar, white rectangle is added into bar as you can see on picture.

I couldn't find the option in API Documents to not to add.

I have found a solution in `css` way thanks to [Dr. Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137956/4995316) but it would be better to know to stop it in options.

```
rect[fill-opacity]{ stroke-width:0 !important; }
```

[Googlechart bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7LhH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the *white rectangle* is to show visually that the bar is selected

the only option that will prevent this is --> `enableInteractivity: false`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Year'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Category A'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Category B'});

    dataTable.addRows([
      ['2014', 1000, 2000],
      ['2015', 2000, 4000],
      ['2016', 3000, 6000],
    ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      enableInteractivity: false,
      height: 600,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pointSize: 4,
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

if you would like to keep *some* interactivity and only lose the selection,

you can cancel the selection by using the `'select'` event listener

when `'select'` fires, pass an empty array (`[]`) to the chart's `setSelection` method

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Year'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Category A'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Category B'});

    dataTable.addRows([
      ['2014', 1000, 2000],
      ['2015', 2000, 4000],
      ['2016', 3000, 6000],
    ]);

    // use 'select' listener to disable selection
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      chart.setSelection([]);
    });

    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      height: 600,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pointSize: 4,
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```